# Is there a way to test an application deployed with Zappa?

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, zappa

I have created a Django application which is deployed to AWS using Zappa in a CI/CD pipeline using the following commands:

```yaml
- zappa update $ENVIRONMENT
- zappa manage $ENVIRONMENT "collectstatic --noinput"
- zappa manage $ENVIRONMENT "migrate"
```

However I want to add a test step to the CI/CD pipeline that would test the application much like in a way that I would test the application locally using the Django command:

```py
python manage.py test
```

Is there a way to issue a zappa command to make run the "python manage.py test"? Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the docs that have a docker setup that you can use for local testing ([Docs here](https://romandc.com/zappa-django-guide/setup/#create-a-dockerfile))

Also, this post from Ian Whitestone(a core Zappa contributor) uses the official AWS docker image for the same job. And he has given one example for local testing also ([Blog post](https://ianwhitestone.work/zappa-serverless-docker/))